# True *args and **kwargs in Python C extension

Tags: python-3.x, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am developing Python 3 C extension.

Can I get the equivalent or arbitrary positional or keyword arguments?

For instance, in Python, I can write:

```py
def fun(name, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something with name and parent
    # do something with args and kwargs
    pass
```

But I cannot find of a simple equivalent in C. While we can perfectly write functions with `PyObject* args` and `PyObject* kwargs`, I cannot easily "parse out" name and parent from whichever (args/kwargs) it came.

Take:

```c
static PyObject* myFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs) {
    char* kwds[] = {"parent", "name", NULL};
    PyObject* name = NULL;
    PyObject* parent = NULL;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "OO", kwds, &parent, &name)) {
        goto errorParseTupleAndKeywords;
    }
    /* Do something with name and parent */
    /* parent and name maybe have appeared either in args or kwargs */
    /* But I don't have any extra positional (*args) or keyword (**kwargs) here */    
}
```

A "manual" approach that I could think of looks roughly like:

```c
static PyObject* myFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs) {
    PyObject* name = NULL;
    PyObject* parent = NULL;
    int inKwargs = 0;
    // Pretend to do something with parent
    if (PyDict_GetItemString(kwargs, "parent")) {
        inKwargs++;
        PyDict_DelItemString(kwargs, "parent");
    }
    // Pretend to do something with name
    if (PyDict_GetItemString(kwargs, "name")) {
        inKwargs++;
        PyDict_DelItemString(kwargs, "name");
    }
    // Not sure if -1 works here
    PyObject* newArgs = PyTuple_GetSlice(args, inKwargs, -1); // this is *args
    // the remaining kwargs can be used as **kwargs
}
```

Comment: Both `args` and `kwargs` aren't something special, just conventional tuples and dictionaries!

Answer (score 3):

In the C API, `PyObject* args` really is a Python tuple, and `PyObject* kwargs` really is a Python dictionary. At least that is what [`PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` internally](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Python/getargs.c#l1318) requires:

```
int PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(PyObject *args, PyObject *keywords, const char *format, char **kwlist, ...)
{
    // …
    if ((args == NULL || !PyTuple_Check(args)) ||
        (keywords != NULL && !PyDict_Check(keywords)) ||
        format == NULL ||
        kwlist == NULL)
    {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return 0;
    }

    // …
}
```

The actual implementation of that function in [`vgetargskeywords`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Python/getargs.c#l1434) also asserts this again, so you should be fine with replacing your `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` call with manual extraction from the objects.

This means that you can use both the [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html) and [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html) APIs, or use the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iter.html) to iterate over the items in these objects.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that `PyObject* args` is a tuple and `PyObject* kwargs` a dictionary; in the third code block from the question (the "manual" approach), I'm using the tuple and dict APIs. The downside is that the code takes an excruciating amount of space and is not too readable, i.e. you can't immediately tell from those ~15 lines that the intention was to make a signature like `def fun(name, parent, *args, **kwargs)`.